# findByAttributes Example

Tags: yii, yii-cactiverecord

Explanation for the use of `$condition` and `$param` in `findByAttributes` in Yii

In most case, this is how I use `findByAttributes`

```
Person::model()->findByAttributes(array('first_name'=>$firstName,'last_name'=>$lastName));
```

Comment: Did you read [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#reading-record) first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy from this thread http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/21178-findbyattributes-example/
Explain what you want to do and where is your errors. 
Try to read documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findByAttributes-detail

Comment: Ill go through the Documentation provided i wanted the explanation for the source code of findByAttributes()

Comment: And Sorry for posting the similar thread it was done by mistake

Answer (score 2):

When you do a find in Yii's CActiveRecord using the attributes of the model, you would most likely find by some equality.

```
Person::model()->findByAttributes(array(
  'first_name' => $firstName,
  'last_name' => $lastName,
));
```

In English, this translates to "Find me a person whose last name is $lastname and whose first name is $firstname". But this is a bad example. Consider the following.

```
Person::model()->findByAttributes(array(
  'age' => 18,
));
```

This is a better example which translates, in English, to "Fetch me all eighteen year olds" (that is, "where `age = 18`). This can be re-written with conditions like so

```
Person::model()->findByAttributes(array(
  'condition' => 'age = :age',
  'params' => array(
    ':age' => 18,
  ),
));
```

So far, there may seem to be little benefits. But such expressions make us able to use more boolean operators. For example...

```
Person::model()->findByAttributes(array(
  'condition' => 'age < :age',
  'params' => array(
    ':age' => 18,
  ),
));
```

...can now help us find all those below a certain age.

The query can grow as complex as you wish with `$conditions` and `$params`, but with your normal method, you may only use assignment queries.

Comment: To make it work with yii 1.x you have to add an array():
Person::model()->findByAttributes(array(), array(
  'condition' => 'age < :age',
  'params' => array(
    ':age' => 18,
  ),
));